# How can I make sure a paragraph stay one the same page using IText5 in HTML

Tags: html, itext

I want to make sure certain parts of a HTML file always stay on the same page, if it is to big make a new page. Is there any attribute I can set or a specific element that I can use that will achieve this?

For example:

[stick together on same page]
**My headline**

First paragraph text 
[/stick together on same page]

Second paragraph text